# I want to give relative path in the project. Currently i have given absolute path in the project

Tags: c#, import-from-excel

I have Coded UI solution which is scripted using C#. I have written a fucntion to pull the records from Excel Sheet and the Excel sheet is placed inside the Project. Currently i am using Absolute path reference for the Excel File. Below the path is shown in Ex:
For Ex: string con = A"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = E:\Main Folder\Sub Folder\Test.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1,HDR=NO:'".

Now, Instead of Absolute Path, i want to give the Relative Path, Can any one help me with this issue??

Solution would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the Application object property ExecutablePath or the Executing Assembly's path. both can give you the location , from your app is started, like, if in development it will be your solution directory and then bin folder or if installed on c drive "program files" then c:/program files and then your app folder. for more details you can read the following links, thanks

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

and

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx